# Register IOS image in GNS3

Tags: networking, emulation, cisco

I've installed gns3 and when I want to make any topologies with elements from left side panel I get this error: `Please register at least one IOS image`
How can I fixed it? I suppose that I have to get a file image but Google doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a 3640.  Use the ios image included in your service plan.  Insert this image in your config.  For details check out blindhog.net.